Recycle buying soda problem
there is a question：
"
If a bottle of soda costs \$1 and you can exchange two empty bottles for one soda, how many sodas can you drink with \$20
"
calculateTotalDrinks[initialMoney_] := 
  Module[{drink = initialMoney, empty = initialMoney, newDrinks}, 
   NestWhile[(newDrinks = Quotient[#[[2]], 2];
       drink += newDrinks;
       empty = newDrinks + Mod[#[[2]], 2];
       {drink, empty}) &, {drink, empty}, #[[2]] >= 2 &][[1]]];

calculateTotalDrinks@20

out: 39
What better way?

What do you mean by "after drinking two empty bottles for a bottle of soda"?

@xzczd The translation is not quite accurate, I have revised it

exchange[{money_, emptybottle_, soda_}] := 
 drink@{0, Mod[emptybottle, 2], money + Quotient[emptybottle, 2]}

drink[{money_, emptybottle_, soda_}] /; soda > 0 := 
 exchange@{money, emptybottle + Sow@soda, 0}

Reap[exchange@{20, 0, 0}][[-1, 1]] // Total
(* 39 *)

A slightly different implementation:
exchange[money_, emptybottle_, soda_, {record___}] := 
 drink[0, Mod[emptybottle, 2], money + Quotient[emptybottle, 2], {record}]

drink[money_, emptybottle_, soda_?Positive, {record___}] := 
 exchange[money, emptybottle + soda, 0, {record, soda}]

exchange[20, 0, 0, {}]
(* drink[0, 1, 0, {20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 1}] *)

Total@Last@%
(* 39 *)


Why use the Reap and Sow functions? incomprehension?

@我心永恒 What do you mean by "incomprehension?"?

s price of soda without bottle, b price of empty bottle, k number of drunk sodas.
SolveValues[{s + b == 1, 2 b == s + b, k s + b == 20}, k, {s, b}] // Floor


{39}


There is no need for Floor. Why did you add it?

@mattiav27 In this special case not but in general yes. For example if it was three empty bottles for one soda instead of two.
